# how to run cron on a module function in drupal?

Tags: drupal, cron, drupal-7

I have a function in a custom module retrieving data from a sql table. I need to run cron at every X minutes to submit these data to a remote url. Any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You should enable a cronjob on your server.

Go to admin/config/system/cron on your page and copy the url to run the cron from outside the site.

Log in to your server as the user that owns the project or as www-data and type `crontab -e`

Now you can add a line like this:

```
*/15 * * * * curl -Lk http://your.site.com/cron.php?cron_key=YOURCRONKEY
```

This statement will trigger the cronjob of your.site.com every 15 Minutes